# How do I disable notifications when someone posts on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

A while ago, I asked Google+ to get a notification when a particular user posts. Today I find that this creates too many notifications, but I can't find how to disable that.

I've tried unfollowing and following that user, I've looked in my settings, and tried to find that option in the new interface as well as in the old one.

Does anyone know where that option lies ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want disable notifications for a particular person, just mute that person.

From [Google+ Help](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1619779?hl=en): **Mute a person or page**

From your **computer**:

> 1. Open [Google+](https://plus.google.com/collections/featured).
> 2. Go to the profile or page you want to mute.
> 3. Below the profile photo and info, click the drop-down arrow.
> 4. Click **Mute [person/page] > Mute**.

To unmute, follow the steps above. Then select **Unmute**.

Or you can [change your Google+ notification settings](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1054277?hl=en)

> **Turn email notifications on or off**
>
> > 1. Go to your **Google+ Settings**.
> > 2. Scroll down to the "Receive notifications" section and click each heading to open that section.
> > 3. Check or uncheck the types of notifications you'd like to receive.
>
> **Turn push notifications on or off**
>
> > 1. Go to your **Google+ Settings**.
> > 2. Scroll down to the "Notification delivery" section.
> > 3. Under the "Phone" section, choose one of these options:
> >
> >    - Push notifications
> >    - Don't notify me

Comment: I tried muting the guy, but Google+ informs me that:"You will not be notified when he:
+mentions you, shares a post with you"

Comment: What a weird system. I don't get notification for every person I follow on G+, only this guy.